# DIV BOX I want it to not affect the keywords on site

Tags: html

Hope you can help, my website host has been a bit sneaky, they have added a user agreement that basically is filled with their name 32 times in fact. It's completely thrown my keyword analytics with my nearest closest keyword ranking 10th most popular after user, agreement 'host name' and so on.

The button is situated on my footer under user agreement, there is no way I can take it off but there is a HTML code box that I can override (but don't get to see the code).

Lewisfackrell.co.uk

Could someone please look at this for me and help it block from being seen or read by Google, even better get rid of it all together. They have added it to everyone's website which is very frustrating.

Cheers
Lewis

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207211/is-there-a-way-to-make-robots-ignore-certain-text) and [this document](https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/) you can block google crawler from crawling a specifig portion of your website with `<!--googleoff: index-->`, for example:

```
<p>This is normal (X)HTML content that will be indexed by Google.</p>

<!--googleoff: index-->

<p>This (X)HTML content will NOT be indexed by Google.</p>

<!--googleon: index>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So will that block that portion of text or will it block individual words based in that block? Also will that affect Google rankings being that I'll be hiding content?

Comment: It will just block Google from analyzing that portion of your website, it won't hide anything, just blocking the crawlers. And I don't think it will affect your Google ranking.

Comment: Cheers! What if I can't find the HTML code as they've posted it as a default, is there a way to say hey this is the bit I want to block

Comment: I think there's no way around it if they were the ones who embed that piece of code to your website.